# default value for dropdown list using thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a dropdown list, status: having 4 states( Estimated, budgetted, processed, finished).
Each unique ID has a possibility to have one of these these 4 status values
I use thymeleaf to display all the status values dynamically.

Now the requirement is to open a particular ID, and then update the status. BEfore doing so, it should show the current value of the status( from the db).

I pass the required information from my controller class:

controller.java

```
StatusTable st = new StatusTable();
List<String>statusValues = st.getAllStatus();
String status = st.getStatus(100); //Herre the status is processed
model.addAttribute("statusdef", statusval)
model.addAttribute("status", statusValues )
return "form.html";
```

form.html

```
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5">
    <body>
    <div th:fragment="editdata">
        <div class="container-md">
            <a style="font-weight: bold">Edit the Status</a>
            <div class="row justify-content-md-end">
                <form>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-2">
                            <a>Status</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example"
                                name="status" th:selected ="${statusdef}"  required>
                                <option th:each="statusvalue : ${status}"
                                    th:text="${statusvalue}">
                            </select>
                          </div>
                         </div>
                        </form>
                        </div>
                         </div>




</body>
```

When I do this, I see that it does not show the default value (processed), it shows the firstvalue  (Estimated)
I want it to show "processed".. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using th:seleceted at wrong place, it must be with option tag and must evaluate to true, like below -

```
  <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example"
        name="status"  required>
       <option th:each="statusvalue : ${status}"
            th:selected ="${statusdef==statusvalue}"
            th:text="${statusvalue}">
       </option>
    </select>
```